# Unexpected behavior in asynchronous JavaScript API call

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I make an API call to `ContractService.getAppData()`. The object it returns, `appDataResult`
will always contain a `success` key which will be a `boolean`.

The issue is that the request succeeds, but before it prints `console.log('success')`, it prints `console.log('failure')`. Meaning the request is interpreted as failed at first, which effects the related logic which is important to the app state.

```
const fetchAppData = async () => {
  try {
    const appDataResult = await ContractService.getAppData()
    if (appDataResult.success) {
      console.log('success')
     // Related logic
    } else {
      console.log('failure')
     // Related logic
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}
```

The `fetchAppData` function is called from a `useEffect` like so:

```
 useEffect(() => {
  if(isLoggedIn && isSelectedAsset) {
    fetchAppData()
  }
 }, [isLoggedIn, isSelectedAsset])
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The function is being called twice. The only way for an if/else to run both the if and the else is if the if/else is being ran twice with a different values.

Comment: How are you calling `fetchAppData`? The code you are showing here seems fine. So the error is probably happening when calling this function.

Comment: Bu the failure is logged first. When in fact it shouldn't print at all, it always succeeds or fails. Shouldn't two runs log the same value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UseEffect being called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62631053/useeffect-being-called-multiple-times)

Comment: If you are making two requests to the server (as suggested by your result), it's not completely unexpected that the failure would happen first. If the first request sent locks a resource that the second needs, the second may fail immediately and finish before the first, thus logging failure before success

Comment: You can easily determine whether your code is being called twice by setting a breakpoint at `if (appDataResult.success) {` and see how many times it is called. You also need to trace where `isLoggedIn` and `isSelectedAsset` are getting changed because apparently at some point they are both true, then one is false, then both are true again.

Comment: Thank you all. It does make a first call too early, when a specific element of the request is not ready yet which prints the failure, then makes another call with that element ready and I get success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way it can print `failure`, then `success`, is if your function is being called twice. You need to check where `fetchAppData()` is being called.

Also, to get another obvious failure out of the way - is there another `console.log('failure')` anywhere?

Comment: Thanks. as I wrote in the comments it does make two calls which create the mess.