# Fetching data using API get request duplicate the response result data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I am doing get request to backend to fetch data from database,
Im doing something like :

```
   const loadData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(URL);
        const data = await response.json();
        setOrdersData(data.data);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        loadData();
        console.log(OrdersData)
    }, []);
```

when i `console.log(OrdersData)` it `console.log` 6 times thus in rendering the data it rendering it 6 times as well, i also tried to set dependency in `useEffect` like as follow:

```
 const loadData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(URL);
        const data = await response.json();

        setOrdersData(data.data);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        loadData();
        setLoading(false)
        console.log(OrdersData)
    }, [loading]);
```

But still when i render `OrdersData` it rendering it 6 times even though the response result is only one object, i couldn't figure it out how to not duplicate the data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UseEffect being called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62631053/useeffect-being-called-multiple-times)

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad no still rendering same data more than once

Answer (score 0):

To prevent unnecessary renders try to use the useCallback hook in the loadData as so:

```
const loadData = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(URL);
        const data = await response.json();

        setOrdersData(data.data);
    } catch (err) {
      //do something
    }
  }, [])
```

Remember to import as hook, and use the dependecies as you please like useEffect or useMemo.
Hoping it works remember also to unmount the the side effects in useEffect with return statement

Comment: i have followed your answer but till getting same issue