# Why useEffect invoked two times, when redux toolkit function dispatched

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I was checked everything, All sections are working good but when I triggered a dispatch ,their dependencies invoked two time!

Bellow is my reducer function :

```
recieveMessage(
  state,
  { payload: { message, topic } }: PayloadAction<IWebSocket>,
) {
  console.log('Recive Message from websocket ', message, topic)
  state.recive = { message, topic }
},
```

and useEffect

```
const { socketReducer: { recive } } = useSelector(RootSelector);

useEffect(() => {
    recive && console.log("Fetch from redux")
}, [recive])
```

Why it fired two time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why useEffect running twice and how to handle it well in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/why-useeffect-running-twice-and-how-to-handle-it-well-in-react)

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: Why not? Why doesn't it apply to your question? From all the information you have provided so far, the first answer is also the answer to your question.

Comment: I wonder why , It wont work

Comment: React - in dev mode - deliberately calls all hooks twice. It's by design. It's mentioned in the linked question. It's mentioned in the React documentation.

Comment: It fired when i listen to redux state