# why does my event run multiple times in useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-hooks, document

i could not understand why **handler** in **useEffect** runs **multiple times**, i know that my **useEffect** runs for the **first time** but i didn't **understand** why **handler** in **useEffect** runs **multiple times**.

```
useEffect(() => {
    
    const keys = [];
    const handler = (e) => {
      
      keys.push(e.keyCode);

      const getItemsFiltered = keys
        .slice(0)
        .slice(Math.max(keys.length - 3, 0))
        .join("");

      if (getItemsFiltered == 1716113) {
        setShow(true);
      }
      console.log(getItemsFiltered);
      if (getItemsFiltered == 1716114) {
        document.getElementById("textField").focus();
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("keydown", handler, false);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("keydown", handler, false);
  }, []);
```

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62631053/useeffect-being-called-multiple-times

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/72238175/8690857

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your handler function reacts to every key press no matter where on the page you click! You can click in a section that's outside of your component, but your handler will still run because you attached your handler method as an event listener to the whole HTML page.

> If you want to run the `handler` function only when you click on your component you can do the following:

```js
document.getElementById("your-div-id").addEventListener("keydown", handler, false);
```

You can also use React's [useRef hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Querying the DOM is a React anti-pattern. I'd swap up your answer to only mention doing it as fallback if there are no other alternatives. Lead with using the React ref since it is the suggested method.