# Nextjs is rendering 4 times and is it normal?

Tags: next.js

```
"use client";
import Dashboard from "./dashboard/page";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("Hiii", "hmm2");
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("Hiii"));
    localStorage.removeItem("Hiii");
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("Hiii"));
  }, []);

  console.log("hmmm");

  // return <Dashboard />;
  return (
    <main className="overflow-x-auto  w-11/12 item-center mx-auto space-y-4"></main>
  );
}
```

I have this code but it renders twice

[image]

As you can see, it renders two times, and is this normal behavior?

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
    reactStrictMode: false,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

I also set `reactStrictMode` to `false` but it does not fix anything.

Comment: You're not disabling strict mode. `reactStrictMode` flag should be outside of the `experimental` flag.

Comment: @ivanatias is right. An since Strict Mode is not deactivated, this might help: [Why useEffect running twice and how to handle it well in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/why-useeffect-running-twice-and-how-to-handle-it-well-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

the solution to your question may have been answered in this link:  [UseEffect being called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62631053/useeffect-being-called-multiple-times)

quoting:

Your `useEffect` is executed only once per render cycle, but you have several state updates in your `useEffect` which cause a re-render. Hence you get a lot of alerts.

Also note that `useEffect` will

- when you provide empty array dependency, your `useEffect` execute once
- when you some value as dependency (eg: `[name]` ), your useEffect execute when name state/prop changes
- useEffect executes on every re-render if you don't pass the dependency array.
  Read here on re-render